# SwitchCompat not showing thumb image on Android 5.0 lollipop emulator

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-switch

I read about the new `SwitchCompat` that has been introduced to implement the Switch widget in Android 5.0. I tried using the same but I am not able to see the drawable thumb image as seen in below image.

[image]

My XML code is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/sampleSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:showText="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/action" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switchStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sampleSwitch"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/status"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am able to see the thumb image in preview design (graphical layout tab in eclipse) for the above layout but when I run my code I dont see the image.

Preview design 
[image]

This is the exception I get

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method '`boolean android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getPadding(android.graphics.Rect)`' on a null object reference

Please can someone help solve the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1704) and you should provide the thumb and track:

```
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
    android:track="@drawable/bg"
```

or

```
    SwitchCompat switchCompat = (SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.sampleSwitch);
    switchCompat.setThumbResource(R.drawable.apptheme_switch_thumb_holo_light);
    switchCompat.setTrackResource(R.drawable.apptheme_switch_track_holo_light);
```

you can use this [link](http://android-holo-colors.com/) to customize it.

### Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/sampleSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:textOn="ON"
        android:text="Toggle Me"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:checked="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### And the codes

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        SwitchCompat switchCompat = (SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.sampleSwitch);
        switchCompat.setThumbResource(R.drawable.apptheme_switch_thumb_holo_light);
        switchCompat.setTrackResource(R.drawable.apptheme_switch_track_holo_light);    
    }

}
```

Comment: but I tried on emulator it gives me the thumb now but when I try to ON and OFF it, it does not react to anything. No matter how much i drag the thumb, the state does not change. is it because of the emulator

Comment: Have you added `android:checked="true"` ?

Comment: yes I tried that but still I am not able to drag the thumb...dragging is not happening now

Comment: I have posted sample code, it runs on Lollipop emulator, If you have any problems tell me to upload it on github, but the project is as simple as above with just importing support library v7 :-)

Comment: Link now goes to generic site that's placeholding the URL.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug with corrupt file in drawable-hdpi on AppCompat
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78262

To fix it, juste override it with this 2 files
https://github.com/lopespm/quick-fix-switchcompat-resources
Add it on your directory drawable-hdpi

XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
android:id="@+id/dev_switch_show_dev_only"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

And nothing was necessary on Java